# Debug with gdb a ROS plugins for Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i have ROS Hydro, Gazebo 1.9 on Ubuntu 13.04. I would debut ROS plugins wrote by me for Gazebo with gdb. I would  insert breakpoints and step through a Gazebo plugin. How can i do this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148361/debug-with-gdb-a-ros-plugins-for-gazebo/) by [Ste](https://answers.ros.org/users/13491/ste/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a `debug` script in the `gazebo_ros` package which you can use in place of `gzserevre` to start gazebo with gdb. Now how you use gdb is outside the scope of this forum. I suggest googling. There is a ton of documentation on using gdb out there.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-10-31**:
Several of the standard launch files support launching with the argument `debug:=true` to launch gazebo in gdb.